# Help Center pages still link to meta.stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, mso-mse-split

Here is one example: [Physics > Help Center > Answering > Why and how are some answers deleted?](//physics.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), which contains a link to this question:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Nothing major as it redirects automatically but it is also easy to fix. Or is this intentional?

Comment: @Oded still wrong in ~142 sites... sorry but this is far from completed unless you want us to start new bug report for each site having the wrong link? (guess we can, but...)

Comment: Fixed on all sites.